# filter + sorting not working in Elastic search

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using Elastic search-1.2.2.

Here I have to do a combination of filter + sort.
Need to get to sorted id value with respect to filter

I don't like to use facet since it was deprecated.
Query filter doesn't support AND filter,so I tried of mentioning boolFilter and specified it as post filter in searchQueryBuilder.
Query:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "sort": [
    {
      "display_order": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "post_filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "and": {
          "filters": [
            {
              "term": {
                "item_ids": ["564279ac-a887-4a0b-99e9-5802b4508747","564279ac-a887-4a0b-99e9-5802b4508447","564279ac-a887-4a0b-99e9-5302b4508747"]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but this query only filter the record,soting not working here.

whether I am doing any thing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overcomplicating the issue -

1. you don't have any aggregation so **post_filter** is not needed
2. you have **bool** and **and** but you have only a single filter
3. You use **term** but have multiple terms

What do you mean by "not working" - do you get an error?

Can you try this simplified query:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/hubware3/message/_search?pretty" -d'
{
  "sort": [
   {
     "display_order": {"order": "asc"}
   }
 ],
 "filter" : {
        "terms" : { "item_ids" : ["564279ac-a887-4a0b-99e9-5802b4508747","564279ac-a887-4a0b-99e9-5802b4508447","564279ac-a887-4a0b-99e9-5302b4508747"]}
      }
   }
}'
```

Comment: yes this query will suite for my particular scenario.

but I am using generic filter function,
which will add a multiple filter in run time.

why I used boolFilter ?
In  order to do multiple filter adjusting depends on run time picked up bool filter.Here my filter logic includes bool filter + (AND or OR or NOT) filter.

Thanks for explained about post_filter,can you please explain me how can I add a bool filter in search QueryBuilder.

I used this line in JAVA
searchQueryBuilder.setPostFilter(boolFilter);

Comment: don't combine a "bool" with "and" - use one or the other.

Comment: so can you please guide me how can I achieve this condition.
(item_id == 1 && name == "John") || (product_id == 234 && vendor !="youtube") && (date >="2014-11-01" && date <="2014-11-18")
Inorder to statisfy this type of conditions I am using combination of bool +AND.
what will be the reason behind for not to use bool + and combination?.

Comment: Can you create a separate question for this?

Comment: I have created the separate question for this(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26997442/how-to-perform-inner-filter-in-elastic-search).any documentation link can be much more helpful for me to understand about Elastic search performance.