# How to perform inner filter in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to do a nested filter stuff in elastic search.

```
(item_id == 1 && name == "John") || (product_id == 234 && vendor !="youtube") && (date >="2014-11-01" && date <="2014-11-18")
```

I refer this link:

```
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/search.html.
```

And performed the post filter operation towards the searchQueryBuilder.but sorting is not woks when we use post filter.

I have already rise question about post filter + sort not working.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26986756/filter-sorting-not-working-in-elastic-search
```

There I got a info about using the post filter only when the aggregation occurred.

Need to know how can I achieve the nester filter + sorting together.

Documentation link will be much help full.

Answer (score 0):

To do everything in a filter:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/hubware3/message/_search?pretty" -d' {
  "filter" : {
    "and" : [{
        "bool" : {
          "should" :[ {
            "bool" : {
              "must" : [
                {"term" : { "item_id" : "1" }},
                {"term" : { "name" : "John" }}
               ]
             }},
            {"bool" : {
              "must" : {
                "term" : { "product_id" : "234" }
             },
             "must_not" : {
                "term" : { "vendor" : "youtube" }
              }
            }
           }
          ]
        }},
        {"range" : {"date " : { "gte" : "2014-11-01","lte" : "2014-11-18"}}}
     ]
  }
}'
```

`and` and `bool must` are interchangeable.

Comment: olly its ok to do in query level,but I need to do in JAVA API level,whether you checked with this link(http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/search.html) I have shared in my question,there they use post filter with out using aggregation.guide me  in a correct direct to achive this in java level.